# How can I do a Impex with collection that have composite key?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, impex

In my project there is a Model that have a relation with another Model (cardinality="many"): Unit has many Organization. This relation is working very well!

So I'm trying (without success) to make the impex below:

```
INSERT_UPDATE Unit;uid[unique=true];organizations(code, site(uid[default='apparel']))[unique=true]
                  ;123456          ;1234,4321
```

And I'm getting error:

```
cannot resolve value '1234,4321' for attribute 'organizations',ignore=false)}
```

I have to do that because there are organizations with the same code in more than one site, so I would do this impex just changing site's uid default.

Do you know another way that can I make this impex or where am I making a mistake in that example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

By `Unit`, I assume you mean `B2BUnit`? ( OOTB `Unit` is used for unit of measurement. e.g. feet, inches ).

Anyway, a collection attribute is not a good attribute/key to use for `unique`. I think it might be better to use unit's ID and the "site" as unique. e.g UnitA in USA, UnitA in Germany, UnitB in USA.